# Using a mocked object in the actual application (Not test)

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

This is my first question here! 
Im trying to use IBM MQ API(allclient) in my spring-boot application, however, I don't have MQ available in all environments. 
I have configured spring to create an MQQueueManager bean, which works fine when I have an actual queue manager running, but when I don't, I cant start my application. 
I wanted to remove the MQQueueManager dependency from my application for when I/ others don't have a queue manager.

To add to the problem this bean is injected into another bean, so removing the MQQueueManager config class would still break my other bean.

I have tried the below code, which I though would load the Mock bean instead of the real bean.

src/main/java/com/app/config

```java
@Configuration 
@Profile("development")
public class MqConfig { 

    @Bean 
    public MQQueueManager connectToQueue(){
      //connection to real QMGR 
     }

}
```

src/test/java/com/app/config

```java
@Configuration 
@Profile("test")
public class MqConfig { 

    @Bean
    public MQQueueManager connectToQueue(){
      return Mockito.mock(MQQueueManager.class); 
     }

}
```

Spring is unable to find any MQQueueManager beans so the app fails to start.

Comment: Hi, good first post with clear code examples. In my view Mockito should only be for test. I'd suggest you look at your design and perhaps wrap the MQQueueManager with your own interface, this give you the option to return a real IBM object in the dev profile and a dummy implementation in the test env. Final question - it's 2019, do you have to use IBM MQ, can you use rabbitmq or some simpler alternative?

Comment: Hi. Yes I agree. Its very counter intuitive to use a mocked object in my actual application. I will have a go at wrapping it in an interface when I get home. I work in a very slow department where MQ is still the standard. We are slowly starting to use micro services :)

Answer (score 0):

Spring-boot has conditional injection. There are a lot of annotations that can be used to conditionally inject beans. I think this is what you try to do. You can see some explanation here: https://iamninad.com/conditional-bean-creation-in-spring-boot/ and here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html.

You should not try to use Mockito outside the test-scope of the application. Mockito (and JUnit) are frameworks for testing and not for production code.

Comment: Thank you Sven. Those links were very helpful! I didn't realise you could have so much control over bean creation. In regards to my problem I think I have found a temp solution. I have used @Lazy on both the component and the autowire and therefore the bean will only get created when used. Obviously this throws an exception if I try and use this interface, but at least my other interfaces can be used without the need for queue manager